# Oracle Lag() on date output wrong data

Tags: oracle, functions, oracle-sql-developer

Oracle DB 19 - Sql developper 19 - NLS DD-MON-RR

I have a table

```
ID      NAME    EFFDT       NODE    PARENT
SHA     DEPT    01-JAN-01   A10200  TOP
SHA     DEPT    04-JAN-11   A10200  X10200
SHA     DEPT    01-JAN-14   A10200  TOP
SHA     DEPT    04-JAN-14   A10200  TOP
```

I'm using `Lag()` function in order to create time period

This is my query :

```
select id
       ,name
       ,effdt
       ,lag(effdt-1,1,null) over (partition by node order by effdt desc) AS EFFDTEND
       ,node
       ,parent
FROM
TABLE
ORDER BY node, effdt
```

Result :

```
ID      NAME    EFFDT       EFFDTEND    NODE    PARENT
SHA     DEPT    01-JAN-01   31-DEC-09   A10200  TOP
SHA     DEPT    04-JAN-11   31-DEC-12   A10200  X10200
SHA     DEPT    01-JAN-14   03-JAN-14   A10200  TOP
SHA     DEPT    04-JAN-14   05-JAN-14   A10200  TOP
```

Look at the first lines, i get `31-DEC-09` in place of `03-JAN-11` and `31-DEC-12` in place of `31-DEC-13`

After `01-JAN-14` everthing works fine!

I already tried to :

1. cast all `effdt` with `TO_DATE()` and NLS template
2. use interval -1 day in place of `effdt-1`

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE('04-JAN-11', 'DD-MON-RR')-1
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns :

```
03-JAN-11
```

### Update

As requested here is the Fiddle link : [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa1e7b72ea49d1c24baf7da4beb8b3d1)

On Fiddle and 18c the error is not reproduced

```
select * from v$version;
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Any idea ?

Comment: That's great - but I'm still a bit unclear as to what the result should be? Could you put a small matrix with your **desired** result into the fiddle below the result also please? That "trick" with `INSERT ALL... SELECT 1 FROM dual;` - where did that come from? It's really cool - instead of multiple `UNION ALL`s... I'm +1'ing the question for that alone (I also normally upvote New Contributors who provide a fiddle! :-) )

Comment: There's a problem with your problem - it appears not be reproducible on Oracle 11 or 18 - maybe uninstall and reinstall your server? Maybe even re-download? What happens on the problem system when you run the code at the bottom of [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b1c87f5b94c7ed6c315ec694abb86fa)?

Comment: `INSERT ALL` comes from the Bible : StackOF :) - In fact the result should be as showed in the Fiddle. The first `EFFDTEND` should be `03-JAN-11` but i get `31-DEC-09`. If i run your script on my env i have the same result as your Fiddle. I can't reinstall the server because i'm part of huge department and this part of work is in charge of another service.

Comment: Set your default date output format `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to a "proper" format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`. I assme then then a light will come to you.

Comment: For debugging, use the same order in the window as in the final query, i.e. `SELECT lag(effdt-1,1,null) over (partition by node order by effdt desc), ... ORDER BY node,effdt desc` Then it becomes more visible.

Comment: Hi @Wernfried, i tried all you said but no light at the end, i still get `2009-12-31` in place of `2011-01-03`. I'm using NLS `DD-MON-RR` because our ITOps ask us to use same NLS settings as DB. `SELECT VALUE "DATABASE" FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why and how it happened but after a refresh by our ITOps of the standby logical DB, my problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK on my 11gXE:

```
SQL> with test (id, name, effdt, node, parent) as
  2    (select 'SHA', 'DEPT', date '2001-01-01', 'A10200', 'TOP'    from dual union all
  3     select 'SHA', 'DEPT', date '2011-01-04', 'A10200', 'X10200' from dual union all
  4     select 'SHA', 'DEPT', date '2014-01-01', 'A10200', 'TOP'    from dual union all
  5     select 'SHA', 'DEPT', date '2014-01-04', 'A10200', 'TOP'    from dual
  6    )
  7  select id, name, effdt,
  8    lag(effdt - 1, 1, null) over (partition by node order by effdt desc) effdtend,
  9    node, parent
 10  from test
 11  order by node, effdt;

ID  NAME EFFDT     EFFDTEND  NODE   PARENT
--- ---- --------- --------- ------ ------
SHA DEPT 01-JAN-01 03-JAN-11 A10200 TOP
SHA DEPT 04-JAN-11 31-DEC-13 A10200 X10200
SHA DEPT 01-JAN-14 03-JAN-14 A10200 TOP
SHA DEPT 04-JAN-14           A10200 TOP

SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL>
```

Comment: We go to 19c recently and i don't get that problem with previous version..